# hibernate query wont work with user input

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

hi there i have a hibernate project which im trying to delete an entry from. code looks like this.

```
import csc1035.hibernate.HibernateUtil;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which entry would you like to delete? ");

        String user_input = scanner.nextLine();

        session.createQuery("delete from StudentEX1 where surname="+user_input).executeUpdate();

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

}
```

it runs fine and deletes the row when i change remove the user_input parameter from the query, and replace it with a string i.e `session.createQuery("delete from StudentEX1 where surname="'Two'").executeUpdate();`, but using user_input variable gives me the error. e.g, im testing the user_input by entering surname "Three", the error: `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Three' in 'where clause'`

I'm just a bit confused as it works fine when there is a normal string, but user input just doesnt seem to work? Note: java displays the query in the console but then goes on to give me an error.

Answer (score 1):

You should never pass user-supplied values directly into a query. Instead, pass parameters. I also suspect you might be wanting a native query here in which case use createNativeQuery instead.

Example:

```java
Query query = session.createNativeQuery("delete from StudentEX1 where surname = ?");
query.setParameter(1, user_input);
query.executeUpdate();
```

I also suggest using camelCase for variable names, ie userInput.

Comment: Brilliant! It works like a charm now, I appreciate the help mate.

Comment: Hi again mate, if you wouldn't mind, I implemented the code into my main program as I was just testing out the functionality previously. Upon implementation, I'm running into the same error unfortunately. I have a Class/Table which I'm trying to delete and I'm writing the delete function in a method in another Class called Manipulation. The classes and code in both programs are set up exactly the same, but still getting the error.

Comment: Edit the post with your new code and I can see if anything pops up?